# How to display an array properly in the browser

Tags: php, arrays

I have just a little question. I searched on the net but I have not found anything.

I use `print_r` or `var_dump` frequently. I'm looking for a method to display an array with these methods properly, with the right format, aligned etc... but not all on one line which makes it incomprehensible.

How can I do this?

Comment: Print where? In command line? Or in HTML?

Comment: Why close and down vote ? Look the answer score...

Comment: @ClémentAndraud The original question (before the edits) was, indeed, incomprehensible. After some editing, it's much better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you're outputting to the browser and want to preserve whitespace, wrap it in `<pre></pre>` tags like so

```
echo '<pre>', var_dump($foo), '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I usually use to dump data to the screen. The HTML pre tag formats it as the output is. Therefor not all data is put on 1 line.

```
<?php
function dump($data)
{
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($data); echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend installing XDebug. Xdebug formats the var_dump and print_r in pretty neat way and with much more information on variables and objects. See the link for more info

http://xdebug.org/docs/display

See the link below for installation

http://xdebug.org/docs/install

Answer (score 0):

Crisps solution is fine. There is an option using the XMP tags as well. You can also use print_r, it brings a bit less data to the output.

```
<?php
function dump($data)
{
  echo "<xmp>";
  //var_dump($data); 
  print_r($data); 
  echo "</xmp>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use FirePHP. It provide an API to debug very nicely.

See http://www.firephp.org/